# Vehicles free database

Tags: uk, europe, database, environment, cars

I am looking for a free vehicle database with information on make, model, year model and fuel type (petrol, diesel, BEV, PHEV, HEV), does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are various datasets online providing information about cars and their respective fuel type. Here are a couple:

- https://www.epa.gov/compliance-and-fuel-economy-data/data-cars-used-testing-fuel-economy
- https://www.fueleconomy.gov/feg/download.shtml
- https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/autompg-dataset